# Call me pointy but what am I?

Tags: riddle

I am round but pointy
Sometimes with stripes and a little bit flashy
And sometimes with patterns and a little bit crispy
If you eat me I am very tasty
But if you hit me I am very bumpy
What am I?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe you are a

> Cone

I am round but pointy

> Round bottom and pointy top

Sometimes with stripes and a little bit flashy

> Traffic cone

And sometimes with patterns and a little bit crispy

> Ice cream cone

If you eat me I am very tasty

> Maybe same as above not sure

But if you hit me I am very bumpy

> As rhsquared said if you hit a traffic cone with you car , it will feel very bumpy

Comment: This must be it!

Comment: @guillau4 I think you are on the right way. The last one - consider doing it with a car.

Comment: Yes, this makes much more sense :)

Comment: @rhsquared to be honest I do not understand the word bumpy very well because I am not a native speaker

Comment: @guillau4 If you ride over some obstacle  (a bump) the car will jump, so you get a bumpy ride.

Comment: @rhsquared somehow I mistook it with the word bouncy. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: Wow good job! Spot on in all clues!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

> [Salak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salak), it fits all clues.

It's round but pointy
Sometimes with stripes and a little bit flashy
Sometimes with patterns and a little bit crispy
If you eat it, it is very tasty
If you throw it on the floor, it is very bumpy

> [image]

Comment: The OP says "If you hit me" not "If you throw me".

Comment: @VioletFlare Sorry, not native English speaker here, I was thinking more like, "If you hit me onto the floor" or something like that...